# Discord.net Send A Slash Command With Bot

Tags: discord, discord.net

I'm trying to have my bot simply send a slash command to a specific discord channel. The command would be read by another bot and executed as needed. Is this possible? I'm using discord.net. I have my bot sending plain text messages to the channel with the code below.

```
await ((ISocketMessageChannel)_client.GetChannel(channelId)).SendMessageAsync("Just Text Here", false, eb.Build());
```

I'm trying to send the command below. The bot that should respond is noted here. (https://www.alphabotsystem.com/guide/charting).

/c aapl 3m macd mfi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the documentation + newest version methods and I'm afraid there is no such functionality.

In addition developers very often secure their bots by adding a condition which ignores executing commands from Webhooks and Bots.